# How to fix two PHP errors I cannot get the plugin author to answer

Tags: wordpress, php

I am the administrator of my website and when I turn debug on to track down a problem on the site, the debug.log is cluttered with hundreds of lines of PHP notices each day about two PHP problems in a plugin, which hides the debug information I am looking for. I tried contacting the author of the plugin to get a fix so I can stop the buildup of the log but he hasn't responded to questions in the forum for the plugin.

What do I need to do to fix these two errors in the WordPress plugin so they stop adding hundreds of PHP notices in the debug.log?

> Trying to get property of non-object in /plugins/custom-author-byline/custom-author-byline.php on line 27

The code on line 27 is

```
$custom_author_uri = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'uri', TRUE);
```

> Undefined index: author_noncename in /plugins/custom-author-byline/custom-author-byline.php on line 80

The code on line 80 is

```
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
```

I am asking this question here because 8 months ago I asked about how to fix these errors in the support forum for the plugin. No one has responded and looking at the support forum, some questions have suggested answers or more comments by other users but nothing from the author for over 6 years.

I hope someone here can help me with this.

Additional information:
The full code around line 27 is the following function.

```
// Replaces the_author_link() output with your custom entry or return the logged in user if there is no custom entry
function custom_author_uri( $author_uri ) {
    //global $authordata;
    global $post, $authordata;
    $custom_author_uri = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'uri', TRUE); 
    if($custom_author_uri)
        return $custom_author_uri;
    return $author_uri;
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'custom_author_uri' );
```

The full code involving line 80 is the following function.

```
function cab_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    global $post, $cab_new_meta_boxes;

    foreach($cab_new_meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ))
            return $post_id;
        } else {
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
            return $post_id;
        }

        $data = $_POST[$meta_box['name']];

        if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name']) == "")
            add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], $data, true);
        elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], true))
            update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], $data);
        elseif($data == "")
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], true));
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'cab_create_meta_box');
add_action('save_post', 'cab_save_postdata');
```

Comment: "nothing from the author for over 6 years." - has the plugin been updated in this time?

Comment: Ah, if this relates to [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-author-byline/) then it seems it was last updated "7 years ago"! As the note at the top of that page states, "It may no longer be maintained or supported and **may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress**." It's straight forward enough to suppress/mask those particular errors, but without knowing the underlying code base, this may only be masking a more serious problem with the code.

Comment: These are both "notices" (not strictly "errors" in the PHP sense). Does the code work OK, apart from these annoying _notices_?

Comment: Yes, the code works OK. I just like things to be clean but if they aren't hurting anything, I'll ignore all the lines they generate in the debug.log. I'll edit the question to add the full code that involves those lines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines as it would be a duplicate question.

Comment: The help center says "This site is for anything that relates to owning, running, or administering your own website." I am the administrator of my website and the debug.log contained hundreds of lines of PHP notices each day about these two problems so I wanted help to stop the continued builup of these PHP notices. Thanks to @DocRoot I did get the answers I needed and I no longer get a debug.log for the site. I will edit the question to add that is why I am asking for help. I had looked at other questions here and many are about WordPress plugins causing problems on a site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "code works OK" and these are *just* E_NOTICE messages (as opposed to *warnings* or *errors*) then you should be able to modify your code like the following in order to workaround these messages:

> Trying to get property of non-object...

We need to check that the `$post` variable is of the expected type before attempting to process it.

```
// Replaces the_author_link() output with your custom entry or return the logged in user if there is no custom entry
function custom_author_uri( $author_uri ) {
    //global $authordata;
    global $post, $authordata;
    if (is_object($post) && property_exists($post,'ID')) {
        $custom_author_uri = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'uri', TRUE); 
        if ($custom_author_uri) {
            return $custom_author_uri;
        }
    }
    return $author_uri;
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'custom_author_uri' );
```

> Undefined index: author_noncename

```
function cab_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    global $post, $cab_new_meta_boxes;

    foreach($cab_new_meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        if (empty($_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'])) {
            return $post_id;
        }
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$meta_box['name'].'_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ))
            return $post_id;
        } else {
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ))
            return $post_id;
        }

        $data = $_POST[$meta_box['name']];

        if(get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name']) == "")
            add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], $data, true);
        elseif($data != get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], true))
            update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], $data);
        elseif($data == "")
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_box['name'], true));
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'cab_create_meta_box');
add_action('save_post', 'cab_save_postdata');
```

Maybe you could *fail* sooner in this second function - but without knowing the code, that is difficult to say. You may need to add further checks if you are still getting "Undefined index" messages.

(Although the nagging thought in the back of my mind is why these functions are being called at all in such circumstances?)

These changes shouldn't make the code run any differently (since you said it "works OK") - it simply avoids the nagging E_NOTICE message(s), assuming that these conditions are normal and expected.

As suggested in your [other question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112071/what-needs-to-be-changed-in-this-preg-match-that-now-generates-a-php-notice-afte), why you are getting these E_NOTICE messages now may simply be a difference in the default error_reporting level after updating to PHP 7. (?)

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the two functions with your markup but there is an error in the first one. The curly brackets are unbalanced and it killed the site. I reversed the direction of the fourth one and the site came back. The E_NOTICE messages have disappeared. Success! Please edit the code to correct the bracket.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, yes, that reversed curly brace was a typo! I've corrected my answer. (That would have resulted in a _fatal parse error_!)